# How to extract video Id from facebook link

Tags: php, video, extract

I have a facebook link linke below:

```
https://www.facebook.com/[user]/videos/vb.xxxxxxxx3/[videoID]/?type=2&theater
```

How can I extract the `VideoId` from the link ?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the video ID with the below code.

```
$url = "https://www.facebook.com/[user]/videos/vb.xxxxxxxx3/[videoID]/?type=2&theater";

$vid = end(explode('/',explode('/?',$url)[0]));
```

Comment: You have accepted this answer and then removed it. What has happened? I am sure that this will work. Please let me know if it's n't working for you.